# Why does the docker container does not run?

Tags: docker, containers

I built a container on a private server running the command `docker build -t image-name .` and then ran it `docker run -it image-name`. But when I check the container list `docker ps`, it doesn't show.

Comment: Depending on what that container does it might have finished its task and ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the container is failing to start and is not listed in the active containers of your server.

1. Try to check the status of all your containers with `docker ps -a` [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).
2. See the logs of the container using [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).